# How to uniqely identify ChromeOS device in Chrome App

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os

I need to find a way of uniquely identifying each device (ChromeBook / ChromeBox) using a Chrome App, I have taken a look through the Chrome App [docs](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps.html) and also at the docs for creating a native plugin using the [pepper api](https://developers.google.com/native-client/dev/).

But I can't see the ability to identify a device in either, just a user (which isn't sufficient for my use).

Can this be done? How can I achive this?

Comment: Did you find a way to uniquely identify ChromeOS devices?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I found that I could create my own and store them on the device but they were only persistent until the user wiped/reset the device which wasn't good enough for my use case.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried using **navigator.userAgent** in your JavaScript? as different devices/OS tend to use some dedicate keywords in the UserAgent string to identify themselves on the Internet.